# How to add html content to sortable area with selected image icon via drag drop?

Tags: jquery

Firstly I want to say, my English is not and I am sorry for the mistakes. I hope i did write a correct description and title about my problem.

I have two column panels. First column for sortable area (with html content) and second column for predefined list with drag drop images.
But when I drag an image from this list, that image should stay there and when I drop that image to sortable area, there should be an html content instead of that image.

https://jsfiddle.net/6c0ohfdp/

For example: if drag drop with "html content 4" image how can I add 4.html file content to sortable area?

Each images have a ID and so we can know which content will come to there. But how can I do this?

SCENARIO:

1) Make drag drop from selected image (I haven't enough info for how to make this)

2) Get drag drop element id (from img id? but how with drag&drop?)

```
var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
```

3) Get html content with this ID from external html file

```
$.get(draggableId+".html", function(data){
var htmldata = $(this).html(data);
});
```

4) Put html content to sortable area

```
$('.temp').append('<div class="temp ui-sortable-handle">'+htmldata+'</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/a1eu2zq8/

Can be made much prettier, but it works. I'll let you work out the nitty gritties that work with your implementation.

1. It reverts blocks back to their original positions. You can choose to remove them instead by using `$(ui.draggable).remove()` in the droppable callback.
2. The HTML, I've inserted, is static since I cannot take it off of a fictional endpoint. Change it accordingly.
3. It checks if an element with the same number ID already exists. If it **doesn't**, it gets added. If it **does**, it will be ignored.

You should consider:

1. Reading the core documentation - https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ - if you haven't.
2. Relying less on IDs for individual elements. The `#wrapper` is fine, but `#1`, `#2`, etc. quickly becomes unreadable and harder to maintain. Instead, use a custom attribute, e.g. `data-id` (which can be used for both dropper and the element being dropped) or even jQuery's `data` function.

Happy coding.

Comment: thank you for your answer and your jsfiddle code. I am trying do more example on your code. Can I ask a few question?
1) When I move a div up or down in "wrapper" shortable area, it's cloning there. For example I did move "html content 2" and did come new "html content temp-2" div. It's possible prevent cloning in wrapper shortable area?
2) How can I do multiple add content from image list instead of one time add?
3) Drag&drop from images contens added to bottom always. It's possible put to specific position? (For example put between html content 1 and html content 2 while dropping)

Comment: 1) I've updated the fiddle link. It now only accepts `img` tags. Modify it as needed. 2) You just iterate over the X number of times you want to add a `div.temp` element. 3) You have to take the position of the element and calculate its vertical (y/top) value with respect to the existing `div.temp` elements. Try to `console.log(event, ui);`. This will give you many of the answers you seek. Though, remember that the vertical offset of the element you drag in must be subtracted from the offset of the `#wrapper` element.